# HikariCP vs. JDBC Metrics Spring Boot2

Tags: java, jdbc, monitoring, hikaricp, spring-boot-2

What is the difference between "hikaricp.connections.*" and "jdbc.connections.*" meter names? I have a Spring Boot 2 application that is defaulting to the Hikari connection pool mechanism and I am tring to understand how to best monitor the database connections in production. After visualizing my metrics in Datadog, I am seeing a slight difference in the metric data for both hikariCP.connections.active and jdbc.connections.active.

Are the JDBC meter names duplicates? Should one be used over the other or does it not matter. I have been struggling to find more detailed documentation on this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

HikariCP is a connection pool and JDBC is the API for managing a connection.
So it can be thought that Spring thinks about separating connection-pool-manager metrics from connection metrics.